# Moving GRUB bootloader from one disk to another (HDD to SSD) to shorten boot time

Tags: grub2, hard-drive, ssd, bootloader

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, but I installed it on the HDD and now I want to move GRUB to my SSD because my system is taking a long time to boot. Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

Comment: It is the files that the boot loader is booting that need to load quickly, not the bootloader.

Comment: yaa plzz tell me..... i m new to linux